# single word for "transformation of a person of least value to a person of great value"

Tags: single-word-requests

Actually I am looking for a suitable word which describes the following or similar:

***A golden era when a person of least importance is transmuted into a person of great importance***

Comment: A commonly used phrase to describe this is *rags to riches*.

Comment: @JonLarby rags to riches means a person's rise from a state of extreme poverty to one of great wealth. I don't think its suitable as a rich person is not always important

Comment: What kind of value are you talking about? Stable boy to epic hero of the kingdom? Overlooked wallflower to dream woman? Bumbling idiot to genius?

Comment: @Helmar I am asking in general. you may say a stable boy to an epic hero of the kingdom.

Comment: @JonLarby The Wikipedia article means that OP is quite wrong to totally discount your suggestion. It is certainly a good answer, and I suggest you make it one. There may – or may not – be a more suitable expression, but I'm almost certain that no single-word answer exists.

Comment: More context would be useful. Perhaps you mean *elevate*.

Comment: Despite an alarming reversal over the last decade or two (in the UK, at least), I'd be pretty sure that *on average* over centuries and millennia social mobility has always tended to *increase*, not decrease. Thus I don't think there ever was a time in the past when beggars routinely rose to become kings. Taking particular note of OP's "golden era", I think we're talking about a *metaphorical / hypothetical* time, commonly identified as ***Once upon a time*** (in fairy tales).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - thanks: the Wikipedia article does make it clear it can used be in a less literal manner.

Comment: Could you please provide a couple of example sentences, or one if you have no flexibility.  I have a word in mind but am not sure if it will work, because I don't know how you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

[Rags to riches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rags_to_riches) is a commonly used phrase to describe this type of transformation. Literally it means to go from poverty to great wealth, but as the Wikipedia article states, it can also be used to describe someone who has gone from "*absolute obscurity to heights of fame.*"